# Is "almost all function" a well defined concept?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am working on a problem which has well defined properties for the vast majority of all PDFs. I would like to make a quantitative statement along the lines of "for almost all distributions, P holds". However, while I know that a set of numbers has (Lebesgue) measure zero if and only if it doesn't contain an interval, I am not familiar with measures over functional spaces.

So here's the concrete question:
Consider all CDF $G:\Sigma\times X\to[0,1]$ over $\Sigma\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, indexed over parameter taken from an interval $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, that admit a differentiable density $g(\sigma\mid x)$ and satisfy the strict monotone likelihood ratio property, i.e. $$\frac{g(\sigma'\mid x)}{g(\sigma\mid x)}<\frac{g(\sigma'\mid x')}{g(\sigma\mid x')}$$
for all $x<x'$ and $\sigma<\sigma'$. Let's call the set of these functions $\mathcal{G}$.

Now, consider the subset $\mathcal{G_0}$ containing only CDFs that have a very specific functional form over an interval. In particular, a CDF is in $\mathcal{G}_0$ *if and only if* there exist $\sigma\leq\sigma'$, real numbers $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}$ and a parameter subinterval $[\underline x,\overline x]\subset X$ such that 
$$G(\sigma'\mid x)=1-\frac{A-B G(\sigma\mid x)}{C-D G(\sigma\mid x)} \qquad\forall x\in[\underline x,\overline x].$$
It seems to me that such a parametric restriction of the function over an entire interval drastically reduces the 'degrees of freedom' of the function, and as such I'm hoping that one could make a statement about how rare this is.
Does $\mathcal{G_0}$ have measure zero among the functional space $\mathcal{G}$? And what 'measure' are we talking about?

**Note:** I've cross-posted this question under https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214563/how-can-i-show-that-almost-all-function-have-property-p