# What space is the set of all CDFs?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

I'm relatively new to functional analysis and am trying to make comparisons across different CDFs (cumulative density functions), i.e. right-continuous, weakly increasing functions $F:\Sigma\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$.

I cannot fit this into the vector space framework since I don't know what a scalar multiplication would mean in such a case. But does there exist some norm over this set, or some category that this space belongs to?

**Question Background:** Maybe it's useful to explain why I'm asking. In fact, this is related to this question: [Is "almost all function" a well defined concept?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391293/is-almost-all-function-a-well-defined-concept)
Essentially, I'm trying to show that certain CDFs are very rare (a "measure-zero" type of argument). Somebody on mathoverflow recommended to look into the notion of [shy sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalent_and_shy_sets), but this applies to topological vector spaces. And of course CDFs are already "very rare" among functions, so I currently only see how I could say that CDFs are shy sets among all functions. But that's not what I need, of course. I want to say that those with my property are shy among the space of CDFs. Hence I need some structure over the set of CDFs so I can look into applicable notions.

Comment: Surely this is not a vector space because a (non identical) multiple of a CDF is no longer a CDF?

Comment: @Lost1 Yes, I agree – unless one could redefine scalar multiplication somehow...

Comment: @Lost1 We could consider it a vector space over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to avoid that problem. Although I'm not sure how you would deal with addition, perhaps $F+G:=\max\{F,G\}$?

Comment: @Math1000 you mean point wise maximum? clearly that does not work if you take [0,1] interval to be the sample space and a uniform distribution on [0,1/2] and [1/2,1] respectively...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "perhaps" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can view CDFs as a subset of the real functions $X$ of finite total variation on $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $-\infty$ with variation norm:
$$     
                 \|f\|=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}V_{R}^{R}(f).
$$
This is a Banach space. It's related to the dual of continuous functions. I won't say exactly because $\infty$ is always an issue. However, on a finite interval, the space $C[a,b]$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with $\max$ norm $\|f\|=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$ has dual $BV[a,b]$ consisting of all complex functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ that vanish at $a$ (just for normalization.) The dual correspondence is through the Riemann-Stieltjes integral:
$$
                        F_{\mu}(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\mu(t).
$$
In fact, the norm of the linear function is the variation of the representing function:
$$
                       \|F_{\mu}\|_{C[a,b]^{\star}}=V_{a}^{b}(\mu)
$$
Your functions all have norm $1$, and define positive linear functionals. I'm not sure if any of this helps, but it turns it into a classical-looking Functional Analysis formulation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into this a bit more... I'll have to read up on variation norms.

Comment: @ItsmeMimi : This was one of the first dual space characterizations, and it helped to start Functional Analysis. This is essentially the original Riesz representation, and was done ~1910 by Riesz. The simplest argument is to use the Hahn Banach theorem to extend $F \in C[a,b]^{\star}$ to $\tilde{F} \in L^{\infty}[a,b]^{\star}$. Then you can look at $\mu(t)=\tilde{F}(\chi_{[a,t]})$, show this is of bounded variation, and show that $F(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\mu(t)$ for $f\in C[a,b]$ (The integral is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.) That's an elegant argument.

Comment: I've looked into this and I think I kind of understand the norming aspect of it. However, how can this space be closed under addition or scalar multiplication? What are the corresponding vector operations?

Comment: @ItsmeMimi : Yes, it's a normed linear space. Normalize the functions to all vanish at some common point, just for convenience, or add the value of the function at a fixed point into the norm: $\|\mu\|=|\mu(0)|+V(\mu)$. Either has the same effect. The sum of two functions of bounded variation is of bounded variation, and variation functions as a norm; the triangle inequality does hold: $V(\mu_1+\mu_2) \le V(\mu_1)+V(\mu_2)$. And, being a dual, it is a Banach space.

Comment: I understand that the sum is also of *bounded* variation, and as such I see that the space of BV functions is closed. However, if I only consider the subspace of those with norm exactly 1, that does not seem to be closed under addition since for two differentiable and nondecreasing functions, $$\int |F'(x)+G'(x)| dx=\int |F'(x)| dx+\int |G'(x)| dx =2.$$ Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @ItsmeMimi You're dealing with the subset of the unit sphere that is the positive cone. The functions are non-decreasing with total variation 1. Such functions are closed under positive convex combinations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26978/discussion-between-itsmemimi-and-trialanderror).